# Address values are not having exact difference as structure length defined. [C]

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address

1. Defined a struture with one variable in it. Lengthof it is 51.
2. Allocating 4 blocks of memory for this. And taking input from the user.
3. Printing the output with the address of the variable.
4. There is a difference of 33 between two address, is not it 51?

   ```
       NULL_NAME =  51

   /*Define structure to hold players name.*/
   typedef struct{
       char name [NULL_NAME];
   } player;

   players=(player*) malloc(4*sizeof(player));

   for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      scanf("%s",p[i].name);
   }

   for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
      printf("%s \n",players[j].name);
      printf("%p \n",&players[j].name);
   }
   ```

Output:-

[image: Output with input values and address]

gcc:
gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-12) 6.3.0 20170406
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Please format your code properly and post a real program that compiles

Comment: Please format your post and include a readable [mcve]

Comment: hint: what is 33 in hex, converted to decimal?

Comment: 33 hex = 3×16+3 = 51

Answer (score 1):

When using printf with %p it prints the pointer address as hex. this is noted also at the printed address which starts with **0x**  (hex prefix). that's why you got offset of 33 (hex) which is 51 bytes.

to see the offset as decimal value add the following line to your last for loop:

```
if ( j > 0 )
     printf(" offset is %ld\n", (players[j].name-players[j-1].name) );
```

you'll get output 51 (decimal)

Comment: It works, but is not guaranteed to work by the C Standard: `(players[j].name-players[j-1].name)` technically has undefined behavior because you are substracting 2 pointers that do not point to the same array. You should use `(uintptr_t)players[j].name - (uintptr_t)players[j - 1].name`

Comment: @chqrlie: That is not guaranteed either. The C standard does not guarantee that converting a pointer to `uintptr_t` yields a simple representation of an address in a flat address space. Better would be `(char *) &players[j] - (char *) &players[j-1]`, which works because any object pointer may be converted to a character pointer, these are both pointers into the same object (the array of `player`), and the difference will be a number of bytes (as a `ptrdiff_t`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I guess you are right: the language of the Standard in C11 6.5.6p9 is a tad ambiguous: *When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object...* It does not say that the pointers must have the type *pointer to array element type*. Note however that `(char *)&players[j]` is the same as `players[j].name` since a pointer to a structure can be safely cast to a pointer to its first member, and vice versa, so the OPs syntax should be OK too, yet these pointers do not point to the same array.